# Boto3 : describe_db_instances() returns a single result only

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, generator, amazon-rds, boto3

Could anyone take a look to my issue please?

I'm trying to retrieve DB information from RDS.
I have multiple databases in it but when I try to describe these with the Boto3 method `describe_db_instances()`, it only returns one instance in the JSON output.

I also tried making it with this generator :

```
def all_rds_instances(region, page_size=20):
            """
            Gets all the RDS instances in a generator (lazy iterator) so you can implement it as:
            `for instance in all_rds_instances(region):`

            page_size [explain what this does] should be bound between 20 and 100.
            """
            client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
            marker = ""
            pool = []
            while True:
                    for instance in pool:
                            yield instance

                    if marker is None:
                            break
                    result = client.describe_db_instances(MaxRecords=page_size, Marker=marker)
                    marker = result.get("Marker")
                    pool = result.get("DBInstances")
```

but when I `next()` it the second time, I got the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testit.py", line 51, in 
>       print next(test)
>   StopIteration

with: `test = all_rds_instances("eu-west-1")`

It's like the API only sees one instance in my RDS as there are multiple ones.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw contents of `result` to see whether multiple db instances are returned? If you use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to run `aws rds describe-db-instances`, how many are returned? Also, please note that Aurora uses `describe-db-clusters`.

Comment: Hi, when i use AWS CLI many results are returned but only one when i use the boto3 method.
Also, the `print client.describe_db_clusters().get("DBClusterEndpoints")` code does return a "None" response.

Comment: Try initializing with `Marker = None` instead of `Marker = ""`. Failing that, use the [Paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html).

Comment: Hello, after trying so many solutions, it seems there is a problem with my credentials. I am gonna take a look with the team that create the sts roles.